# CSS hide button if text is short or character count is limited

Tags: html, css

I am using the following CSS ONLY code to show or hide full paragraphs. Please refer to the snippet below. Working perfectly! However, we all know that such "Show More" buttons are intended to be displayed only if the text in the paragraph is too long. The problem is that though the button is working fine here and doing its job of showing or hiding text well enough, it still shows up even when the sentence is too short or text is too limited (say like 1 or 2 line texts that can be read easily and do not require the "Show More" button). How can I hide that button and show up only when the text is long enough for the button to actually appear? Also, in case of long sentences when the show more button would actually be shown, I want 3 dots at the end of the sentence (like...) which represents that there are more text to be read. And these 3 dots show go away when the para is expanded and should come back when the para is contracted back.

P.S: I am expecting a CSS ONLY answer. No jQuery or Javascript please as I want to keep it plain and do not want to mess it up all.

```css
.panel-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.show, .hide {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1em;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show:target {
  display: none;
}
.show:target ~ .hide {
  display: block;
}
.show:target ~ .panel {
  max-height: 100%;
}
.show:target ~ .fade {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.panel {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fade {
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-wrapper">
  <a href="#show1" class="show btn" id="show1">Show more</a>
  <a href="#hide1" class="hide btn" id="hide1">Show less</a>
  <div class="panel">
    Let us not wallow in the valley of despair, I say to you today, my friends. And so even though we face the difficulties of today and tomorrow, I still have a dream. It is a dream deeply rooted in the American dream. I have a dream that one day this nation
    will rise up and live out the true meaning of its creed: "We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal." I have a dream that one day on the red hills of Georgia, the sons of former slaves and the sons of former slave owners
    will be able to sit down together at the table of brotherhood. I have a dream that one day even the state of Mississippi, a state sweltering with the heat of injustice, sweltering with the heat of oppression, will be transformed into an oasis of freedom
  </div>
  <div class="fade"></div>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div class="panel-wrapper">
  <a href="#show2" class="show btn" id="show2">Show more</a>
  <a href="#hide2" class="hide btn" id="hide2">Show less</a>
  <div class="panel">
    Let us not wallow in the valley of despair, I say to you today, my friends. And so even though we face the difficulties of today and tomorrow, I still have a dream. It is a dream deeply rooted in the American dream. I have a dream that one day this nation
    will rise up and live out the true meaning of its creed: "We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal." I have a dream that one day on the red hills of Georgia, the sons of former slaves and the sons of former slave owners
    will be able to sit down together at the table of brotherhood. I have a dream that one day even the state of Mississippi, a state sweltering with the heat of injustice, sweltering with the heat of oppression, will be transformed into an oasis of freedom
  </div>
  <div class="fade"></div>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div class="panel-wrapper">
  <a href="#show3" class="show btn" id="show3">Show more</a>
  <a href="#hide3" class="hide btn" id="hide3">Show less</a>
  <div class="panel">
    Consider this short text. Short enough to hide "Show More" button.
  </div>
  <div class="fade"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recreate all the feature differently where I will rely on small hack using `position:sticky` and consider the use of `:active`/`:focus` instead of `:target`.

This cover only your first point. See comment in the code for the details.

<sup>This isn't a perfect solution, it's more an approximation as you will find some drawbacks.</sup>

```css
.wrapper {
  line-height:1.2em; /* explicitely set the height of line to easily control */
  max-height: calc(2*1.2em + 2em); /* Show at max 2 line*/
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .content {
  position:relative;
}
/* This will hide the show/less if the content is 2 lines or less*/
.wrapper .content:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:106%; /* Start at the end of the content */
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:1;
  background:#fff;
  height:100px; /* A big height */
}
/**/
.wrapper :nth-last-child(1),
.wrapper :nth-last-child(2) {
  /*make the element sticky so they show above the content if the content is big
    and the after will no more hide them
  */
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fff;
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
  color:red;
  line-height:2em;
}

.wrapper:focus,
.wrapper:active {
  outline: 0;
  max-height: 400px;
}
/*make the after and the "show more" on click*/
.wrapper:focus .content:after,
.wrapper:active .content:after,
.wrapper:focus :nth-last-child(1),
.wrapper:active :nth-last-child(1) {
  display:none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" tabindex=-1>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ipsum nunc, hendrerit ac arcu eu, pulvinar ultrices enim. Ut at enim bibendum, iaculis turpis ac, congue dui. Etiam faucibus lectus eget lorem molestie, finibus aliquet quam pretium. Donec
    eget tellus porta, sollicitudin massa quis, eget tellus porta, sollicitudin massa quis, eget tellus porta, sollicitudin massa quis, eget tellus porta, sollicitudin massa quis, eget tellus porta, sollicitudin massa quis, eget tellus porta, sollicitudin
    massa quis, eget tellus porta, sollicitudin massa quis,</div>
  <div tabindex=-1>show less</div>
  <div>Show more</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" tabindex=-1>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div tabindex=-1>show less</div>
  <div>Show more</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" tabindex=-1>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor eget tellus porta, sollicitudin massa quis, eget tellus porta, sollicitudin</div>
  <div tabindex=-1>show less</div>
  <div>Show more</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" tabindex=-1>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor eget tellus porta, sollicitudin massa quis, eget tellus porta, sollicitudin eget tellus porta, sollicitudin sollicitudin eget tellus porta, sollicitudin</div>
  <div tabindex=-1>show less</div>
  <div>Show more</div>
</div>
```